# Reindexing array of objects in Javascript (no splice)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How should I index an array of objects?

Let's say I have this structure:

```
var list = [
    { index : 1, text : "aaa" },
    { index : 2, text : "bbb" },
    { index : 3, text : "ccc" }
];
```

And I want to delete the second one. What would be the best way to reindex this array?

What happens if I delete several elements?

The reason I can't just use a splice is because this array is built from several  instantiated objects. So the array is a list of objects pointing to a key in another object.

**Edit** : I'm using FabricJS objects. Let's say I have three FabricJS text objects on a canvas, each text object has a custom attribute that gives its position on a list.

So if I remove one text object, I have to update the other text objects.

Thanks!

Comment: And why wouldn't `splice()` work here?

Comment: Why is that a problem? Use `splice`.

Comment: I don't know how is your data structure but may not be better to use an array and use the array position as an index? Other wise you will have to reindex all the items on that list and that will not be efficient if it is a long list.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, you cannot use splice because you will need the index 3 becoming index 2 if you remove the second item right?

Comment: by `reindex` do you mean to change a value of the `index` key of all the objects when you delete some of them?

Comment: Basically, I'm using FabricJS objects with custom attributes (position in a list) added to them.
If I delete one FabricJS object, I need to reindex, for example the one with an attribute index : 3 becomes index : 2.
The problem is, each FabricJS is a standalone object and I can build a temporary array containing all the attributes but I still have to reorder them.

Answer (score 4):

you could potentially use `.filter()`

```
var index_to_delete = 2; //just example..
list = list.filter(function (item) {
  return item.index !== index_to_delete;
});
```

and then if you want to rebuild your indexes you could use `.map()`

```
list = list.map(function (item, index) {
   item.index = index;
   return item;
});
```

alternatively you could use `.reduce()` to perform the above in one go..

```
list = list.reduce(function (accum, item, index) {
  if (item.index !== index_to_delete) {
    item.index = index;
    accum.push(item);
  }
  return accum;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and thinking that the problem is the data structure is maybe not the best, I will use something like this:

```
function removeItem (index /* int */) {
    list = list.splice(index, 1);
    for (var i = index; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].index = list[i].index - 1;
    }
}
```

But again, if it is an ordered list from index 1 to index 10 for example, I will use the array position as the index. If your indexes have gaps (f.i: index 1, index 3, index 6, index 7), you can use something like that.

Answer (score -1):

```
function deleteElement(list, index) {
    var newList = [];
    for (var ix in list) {
        var el = list[ix];
        if (el.index == index)
            continue;

        if (el.index > index)
            el.index--;

        newList.push(el);
    }
    return newList;
}
```

EDIT: Wrapped into general method